# Adjusted labels hidden for nested plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

How do I make adjusted labels in nested plot_grid plots not hide below other plots?

This works fine:

```
# label 'b' is visible on top of figure a
plot_grid(ggdraw(), ggdraw(), nrow=2, labels=c("a", "b"), hjust=c(-0.5, -5), vjust=c(1,-2))
```

[image]

But not this:

```
# label 'b' is invisible below figure a.
plot_grid(ggdraw(), 
      plot_grid(ggdraw(), ggdraw(),
         nrow=2, rel_heights = c(0.4, 0.6), labels=c("b", "c"), hjust=c(-5,-0.5), vjust=c(0.5,0)), 
      nrow=2, rel_heights = c(0.33, 0.66))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clipping issue. `plot_grid()` uses ggplot to draw the grid, and ggplot clips contents that falls outside the plot panel. Your cut-off letter falls partially outside the plot panel:

```
p1 <- ggdraw() + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#FF000080", color = NA))
p2 <- ggdraw() + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#00FF0080", color = NA))
p3 <- ggdraw() + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#0000FF80", color = NA))

row <- plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow=2, rel_heights = c(0.4, 0.6),
          labels=c("b", "c"), hjust=c(-5,-0.5), vjust=c(0.5,0))
plot_grid(p3, row, nrow=2, rel_heights = c(0.33, 0.66))
```

[image]

One solution is to disable this clipping:

```
row_grob <- ggplotGrob(row)
index <- grep("panel", row_grob$layout$name)
row_grob$layout$clip[index] = "off"

plot_grid(p3, row_grob,
          nrow=2, rel_heights = c(0.33, 0.66))
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could draw the labels after you have assembled the whole plot grid, using `draw_label()`.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it would be a good idea to have this option as an argument to plot_grid? Or have clipping off by default?

Comment: To do this properly, it will require a change to the ggplot2 code. I'll see if that is possible.

Comment: I got the relevant code into ggplot2 and just committed a fix for this issue to the cowplot codebase. Should work as expected in a future release. As of right now, I don't recommend using the development version of cowplot, as it's in heavy flux.